# Element from fixed to relative on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a wrapper in which I have animated the same effect as Apple on [their Airpods Pro page](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/). It's basically a video, when I scroll the video plays bit by bit. The video's position is fixed so the text nicely scrolls over it. However, the text is only visible when between the offset of a specific division (text-display).

That part works fine. Now I want that when the user has scrolled to the end of the video, and thus the animation is finished, that **the video-effect-wrapper goes from a fixed position to a relative position. So that website will scroll it's content normally after the video-animation**.

[JSFIDDLE CODE + DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/38ade1gw/)

This is an example of what I already tried:

```
        //If video-animation ended: Make position of video-wrapper relative to continue scrolling
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#video-effect-wrapper").height()) {
            $(video).css("position", "relative");
            $("#video-effect-wrapper .text").css("display", "none");
        }
```

This kind of works... But is everything except smooth. And it also needs to be possible to reverse scroll the webpage backwards.

**Problems I encountered when trying to fix this problem:**

- The scrolling, and transition from fixed to relative needs to feel natural and smooth
- The wrapper itself isn't fixed and contains .text elements, the video is fixed so the .text elements can go over the video element (creating the effect). These .text elements cause problems trying to find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing some reverse engineering on the [Airpods Pro page](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/), we notice that the animation doesn't use a `video`, but a `canvas`. The implementation is as follows:

- Preload about 1500 images over HTTP2, actually the frames of the animation
- Create an array of images in the form of `HTMLImageElement`
- React to every `scroll` DOM event and request an animation frame corresponding to the nearest image, with [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)
- In the animation frame requests callback, display the image by using `ctx.drawImage` (`ctx` being the `2d` context of the `canvas` element)

The [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) function should help you achieve a smoother effect as the frames will be deferred and synchronized with the "frames per second" rate of the target screen.

For more information on how to properly display a frame on a scroll event, you can read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

That being said, concerning your main problem, I have a working solution that consists in:

- Creating a placeholder, of same height and width than the `video` element. Its purpose is to avoid the video to overlap the rest of the HTML when set to `absolute` position
- Into the `scroll` event callback, when the placeholder reaches the top of the viewport, set the video's position to `absolute`, and the right `top` value

The idea is that the video always remains out of the flow, and takes place over the placeholder at the right moment when scrolling to the bottom.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
//Get video element
let video = $("#video-effect-wrapper video").get(0);
video.pause();

let topOffset;

$(window).resize(onResize);

function computeVideoSizeAndPosition() {
    const { width, height } = video.getBoundingClientRect();
    const videoPlaceholder = $("#video-placeholder");
    videoPlaceholder.css("width", width);
    videoPlaceholder.css("height", height);
    topOffset = videoPlaceholder.position().top;
}

function updateVideoPosition() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= topOffset) {
        $(video).css("position", "absolute");
        $(video).css("left", "0px");
        $(video).css("top", topOffset);
    } else {
        $(video).css("position", "fixed");
        $(video).css("left", "0px");
        $(video).css("top", "0px");
    }
}

function onResize() {
    computeVideoSizeAndPosition();
    updateVideoPosition();
}

onResize();

//Initialize video effect wrapper
$(document).ready(function () {

    //If .first text-element is set, place it in bottom of
    //text-display
    if ($("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first").length) {
        //Get text-display position properties
        let textDisplay = $("#video-effect-wrapper #text-display");
        let textDisplayPosition = textDisplay.offset().top;
        let textDisplayHeight = textDisplay.height();
        let textDisplayBottom = textDisplayPosition + textDisplayHeight;

        //Get .text.first positions
        let firstText = $("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first");
        let firstTextHeight = firstText.height();
        let startPositionOfFirstText = textDisplayBottom - firstTextHeight + 50;

        //Set start position of .text.first
        firstText.css("margin-top", startPositionOfFirstText);
    }
});

//Code to launch video-effect when user scrolls
$(document).scroll(function () {

    //Calculate amount of pixels there is scrolled in the video-effect-wrapper
    let n = $(window).scrollTop() - $("#video-effect-wrapper").offset().top + 408;
    n = n < 0 ? 0 : n;

    //If .text.first is set, we need to calculate one less text-box
    let x = $("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first").length == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    //Calculate how many percent of the video-effect-wrapper is currenlty scrolled
    let percentage = n / ($(".text").eq(1).outerHeight(true) * ($("#video-effect-wrapper .text").length - x)) * 100;
    //console.log(percentage);
    //console.log(percentage);

    //Get duration of video
    let duration = video.duration;

    //Calculate to which second in video we need to go
    let skipTo = duration / 100 * percentage;

    //console.log(skipTo);

    //Skip to specified second
    video.currentTime = skipTo;

    //Only allow text-elements to be visible inside text-display
    let textDisplay = $("#video-effect-wrapper #text-display");
    let textDisplayHeight = textDisplay.height();
    let textDisplayTop = textDisplay.offset().top;
    let textDisplayBottom = textDisplayTop + textDisplayHeight;
    $("#video-effect-wrapper .text").each(function (i) {
        let text = $(this);

        if (text.offset().top < textDisplayBottom && text.offset().top > textDisplayTop) {
            let textProgressPoint = textDisplayTop + (textDisplayHeight / 2);
            let textScrollProgressInPx = Math.abs(text.offset().top - textProgressPoint - textDisplayHeight / 2);
            textScrollProgressInPx = textScrollProgressInPx <= 0 ? 0 : textScrollProgressInPx;
            let textScrollProgressInPerc = textScrollProgressInPx / (textDisplayHeight / 2) * 100;

            //console.log(textScrollProgressInPerc);
            if (text.hasClass("first"))
                textScrollProgressInPerc = 100;

            text.css("opacity", textScrollProgressInPerc / 100);
        } else {
            text.css("transition", "0.5s ease");
            text.css("opacity", "0");
        }
    });

    updateVideoPosition();

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="video-effect-wrapper">
    <video muted autoplay>
        <source src="https://ndvibes.com/test/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">
    </video>
    <div id="text-display"/>
    <div class="text first">
        Scroll down to test this little demo
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Still a lot to improve
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        So please help me
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Thanks! :D
    </div>
</div>
<div id="video-placeholder">

</div>
<div id="other-parts-of-website">
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
    <p>
        Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
    </p>
</div>
```

You can try here: https://jsfiddle.net/crkj1m0v/3/

Comment: While this is interesting and useful background on how to implement this type of animation, it doesn't seem especially relevant to @oniel's question, which is specific to how to resume the scrolling of the page once the animation is finished. As O'Niel notes, the association between the scrolling and the playback is already working.

Comment: Thanks for the insight information on how Apple has done it, and an even bigger thanks for the nice and smooth solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the video to lock back in place as you scroll back up, you'll need to mark the place where you switch from `fixed` to `relative`.

```js
//Get video element
let video = $("#video-effect-wrapper video").get(0);
video.pause();

let videoLocked = true;
let lockPoint = -1;
const vidHeight = 408;

//Initialize video effect wrapper
$(document).ready(function() {

  const videoHeight = $("#video-effect-wrapper").height();

  //If .first text-element is set, place it in bottom of
  //text-display
  if ($("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first").length) {
    //Get text-display position properties
    let textDisplay = $("#video-effect-wrapper #text-display");
    let textDisplayPosition = textDisplay.offset().top;
    let textDisplayHeight = textDisplay.height();
    let textDisplayBottom = textDisplayPosition + textDisplayHeight;

    //Get .text.first positions
    let firstText = $("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first");
    let firstTextHeight = firstText.height();
    let startPositionOfFirstText = textDisplayBottom - firstTextHeight + 50;

    //Set start position of .text.first
    firstText.css("margin-top", startPositionOfFirstText);
  }


  //Code to launch video-effect when user scrolls
  $(document).scroll(function() {

    //Calculate amount of pixels there is scrolled in the video-effect-wrapper
    let n = $(window).scrollTop() - $("#video-effect-wrapper").offset().top + vidHeight;
    n = n < 0 ? 0 : n;
    // console.log('n: ' + n);

    //If .text.first is set, we need to calculate one less text-box
    let x = $("#video-effect-wrapper .text.first").length == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    //Calculate how many percent of the video-effect-wrapper is currenlty scrolled
    let percentage = n / ($(".text").eq(1).outerHeight(true) * ($("#video-effect-wrapper .text").length - x)) * 100;
    //console.log(percentage);

    //Get duration of video
    let duration = video.duration;

    //Calculate to which second in video we need to go
    let skipTo = duration / 100 * percentage;

    //console.log(skipTo);

    //Skip to specified second
    video.currentTime = skipTo;

    //Only allow text-elements to be visible inside text-display
    let textDisplay = $("#video-effect-wrapper #text-display");
    let textDisplayHeight = textDisplay.height();
    let textDisplayTop = textDisplay.offset().top;
    let textDisplayBottom = textDisplayTop + textDisplayHeight;
    $("#video-effect-wrapper .text").each(function(i) {
      let text = $(this);

      if (text.offset().top < textDisplayBottom && text.offset().top > textDisplayTop) {
        let textProgressPoint = textDisplayTop + (textDisplayHeight / 2);
        let textScrollProgressInPx = Math.abs(text.offset().top - textProgressPoint - textDisplayHeight / 2);
        textScrollProgressInPx = textScrollProgressInPx <= 0 ? 0 : textScrollProgressInPx;
        let textScrollProgressInPerc = textScrollProgressInPx / (textDisplayHeight / 2) * 100;

        //console.log(textScrollProgressInPerc);
        if (text.hasClass("first"))
          textScrollProgressInPerc = 100;

        text.css("opacity", textScrollProgressInPerc / 100);
      } else {
        text.css("transition", "0.5s ease");
        text.css("opacity", "0");
      }
    });


    //If video-animation ended: Make position of video-wrapper relative to continue scrolling
    if (videoLocked) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= videoHeight) {
        $('video').css("position", "relative");
        videoLocked = false;
        lockPoint = $(window).scrollTop() - 10;
        // I gave it an extra 10px to avoid flickering between locked and unlocked.
      }
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < lockPoint) {
      $('video').css("position", "fixed");
      videoLocked = true;
    }

  });




});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#video-effect-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#video-effect-wrapper video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#video-effect-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #434343, #000000);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -1;
}

#video-effect-wrapper .text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  /*
                background-color: blue;
                */
}

#video-effect-wrapper .text.first {
  margin-top: 50vh;
  opacity: 1;
}

#video-effect-wrapper .text:last-child {
  /*margin-bottom: 100vh;*/
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
}

#video-effect-wrapper #text-display {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  /*
                background-color: red;
                */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-effect-wrapper">
  <video muted autoplay>
            <source src="https://ndvibes.com/test/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">
          </video>

  <div id="text-display"></div>
  <div class="text first">
    Scroll down to test this little demo
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Still a lot to improve
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    So please help me
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Thanks! :D
  </div>
</div>

<div id="other-parts-of-website">
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Normal scroll behaviour wanted.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. This solution gets close but I still encounter one big problem with your code: As soon as the video ends, the video-element's position gets fixed, but there are still white paragraphs animating on the green background. The div #other-parts-of-website should be the first content the user sees after the video-animation.